# Finding the curve with the smallest lowest point with fixed endpoints and fixed length

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations

The optimization problem I am trying to solve is given by

$$\min_{f \in C^2[a,b]} \,\, \inf_{x \in [a,b]} f(x)$$
subject to the constraints
$$\int_a^b\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}\,dx = L$$
, $f(a) = A$ and $f(b) = B$. Here $L,a,b,A,B$ are some constants with $a < b$ and $L$ is greater than the length of the line segment between $(a,A)$ and $(b,B)$.

This is a variation of the well-known catenary problem in which the objective is
$$\min_{f \in C^2[a,b]}\int_a^bf(x)\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}\,dx$$
and the constraints are the same as the ones above.

From a physical point of view what I am wondering is can I distort a chain (one that cannot be elongated) whose end points are fixed such that the lowest point of the chain is lower than what it would be if I let gravity do its thing and did not meddle with the chain at all. My intuition is that it is not possible. If I take a chain hanging in equilibrium from two points on the plane and pull it to the side, its lowest point would move up I think.

I can write
$$\int_a^bf(x)\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}\,dx \geq \inf_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)\int_a^b\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}\,dx = \inf_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)L$$

So the objective of the catenary problem provides an upper bound for the objective of my problem but I don't see if that helps.

Comment: Why is $f\in C^2([a,b])$? The constraints don't need such a thing and I don't think it can be expected. Imagine a smooth line connecting $a$ and $b$. If I push this line down with force at a certain point, I obtain something which is lower and forms a triangle. Hence your solution will probably just be in the Sobolev Space $W^{1,1}$ or more probable be of bounded variation.

Comment: @humanStampedist Thanks for your comment. I was going to write my thoughts on that as well (expand $C^2$ to its closure under some topology maybe) but decided not to. I had considered an example similar to the one you gave before posting this question but I could not prove that that would achieve a smaller lowest point. For simplicity I had considered the symmetric case in which the points the chain is fixed to are at the same vertical level. In my example I was pulling the chain all the way to one side rather than pulling it down, which makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

The minimum is attained if the chain is completely strained. At this case the locus of the infimum is an ellipse whose foci are on $[a,f(a)]$ and $([b,f(b)])$.

Comment: Could you please expand a bit on your last sentence?

Comment: The string is your function $f(x)$ **as long as it's single-valued** while the pencil position $(x,f(x))$, where $a<x<b$, is the infimum point.  The minimum of the infimum point is the minimum of the ellipse.

Comment: The tangent at the lowest point of the ellipse is a line $y=h$ that, by the nature of an ellipse, is met at the same angle by the two lines from $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$ to that point,so the reflection of the second line with respect to the tangent is an extension of the first line that intersects the line $x=b$ at $(b,2h-f(b))$, which leads to a simple computation of $h$ and the position of the tangent point.